# What is a "gearbox"?

Tags: hardware

What is a "gearbox" in the context of networking chips? The term often comes up in conjunction with SERDES (serializer / de-serializer).

Comment: @JesseP. Sorry about the delay; I was waiting to see if a more detailed answer would arrive (none did).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A gearbox is essentially a kind of multiplexer/demultiplexer that’s used to convert multiple serial data streams at one rate to multiple streams at another rate. Serial-to-parallel and parallel-to-serial (SERDES) converters are at the heart of the device. SERDES converters are a specialty of Avago, which has been making them in various forms for years.

This is an excerpt from [this link](https://www.electronicdesign.com/content/serdes-gearbox-phy-simplifies-100-gbits-connectivity), discussing it in more detail.